# Andriod studio device manager not found

Tags: android, sdk, adb

I have installed Arctic fox 2020.3.1. I have not found device manager in view/tool windows. I am able to connect to the device properly. ADB connection is also working. How should I see the device manager?

Answer (score 0):

1. Press Double Shift.
2. Try to write Device Manager ( don't write entire thing but just few words )
3. In the drop down menu's suggestions you will find AVD Manager.

AVD Manager is same as Device Manager in Arctic Fox.

Answer (score -1):

[image]

You need to navigate on the options colored with blue color and you will find your device file explorer on the right sidebar of the Android Studio. I hope these options are seen on your Android Studio version.

Comment: No its not located there.

Comment: no it didn't help as i have to make the correct gradle settings